# Is it possible to define a field with the same name as a keyword?

Tags: rust, serde

I am using Rust to write a REST API and my Flutter client defines the entity like this:

```dart
class WordDefinition {
  String type;
  String name;
  List<String> values;

  WordDefinition({
    this.type,
    this.name,
    this.values,
  });
}
```

The client uses `type` as a entity field name. In Dart it works fine, but in the server side Rust I could not define the field name like this:

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct WordDefinition {
    pub type: String,
    pub text: String,
    pub translations: Vec<String>,
}
```

```
error: expected identifier, found keyword `type`
 --> src/lib.rs:5:9
  |
4 | pub struct WordDefinition {
  |            -------------- while parsing this struct
5 |     pub type: String,
  |         ^^^^ expected identifier, found keyword
```

What should I do to avoid the Rust keyword conflict? Is it possible to define a entity name using `type` like this in Rust?

Comment: Use `r#type`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4c51ba81decd198eeb8bb392a43216df - or you can use a different field name and use `#[serde(rename = "type")]`

Comment: Don't know if it was the case when this question was posted, but the current compiler error contains a help annotation showing what you can do: *"escape `type` to use it as an identifier ... `pub r#type: String`"*.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use "raw identifiers" by prefixing a keyword with`r#` like this:

```rust
struct Foo {
  r#type: String
}
```

You can also give it one name in your Rust code and use `#[serde(rename)]` to serialize to a different name. For example, this changes `kind` into `type` during serialization:

```rust
struct Foo {
  #[serde(rename = "type")]
  kind: String
}
```

Personally, I prefer the second way, because I find `r#type` a bit annoying to type and ugly, but that's just preference, there's not a "right" way

Comment: Renaming the field to something completely different might be surprising. Java, for example, uses clazz (for "class"), which is idiomatic, but looks odd. Personally, I'd suffix with an underscore (so `type_`), but I don't know whether that's idiomatic Rust.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe I replace by `kind` cause it's a lot used even in std https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/?search=kind and kind is a synonym of type https://www.wordreference.com/enfr/kind. I'm never see `type_` and I hate random underscore, like `___python___`. `clazz` look weird and there is no class in Rust anyway. One can use `r#type` if you really want to use `type`

Comment: Hard to say whether it's idiomatic, it's not a pattern I've seen used much, inside rustc the abbreviation `ty` is very common, but as an editor pointed out, `kind` definitely gets used a lot in this context