# Can a struct contain a key consisting only of digits?

Tags: parsing, rust, struct, serde

I have a DB response containing my ID field, which I need, like this:

```
{
  ... other fields
  "0000": "9"
}
```

So I want to make a struct to parse this response to and it should be like:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct PostResponse {
    0000: String, // this key gives an error
}
```

How can I handle this case?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69871539/

Answer (score 2):

I can just rename the field with serde:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct PostResponse {
    #[serde(rename = "0000")]
    id: String
}
```